# pip install editable working dir to custom path using requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt

**Short version:**
Is it possible to use the -e parameter in requirements.txt with a path where the editable package should be installed?

---

**First approach**

requirements.txt:

```
-e git+https://github.com/snake-soft/imap-storage.git#egg=imap-storage
```

**Pro:** Automated install

**Contra:** Editable directory is inside virtualenv src folder (not in workspace)

---

**Second approach** *(Edit: Don't use this until you know what you're doing, look at bottom)*

If i clone the repo and installed it like this (virtualenv activated):

```
cd /home/user/workspace
git clone https://github.com/snake-soft/imap-storage.git
pip install -e .
```

Gives the structure i want:

```
workspace
├── imap-storage
├── django-project  # uses imap-storage module
```

I have what i want. The repository (imap-storage) lays parallel to the django-project, that uses it.
It is importable because it is installed inside the virtualenv.

**Pro:** Editable directory is inside my workspace

**Contra:** Not automated, not intuitive

---

**Goal**

- pip install -r requirements.txt to install module from git (like first approach)
- Module is in pythonpath of virtualenv -> importable
- Editable working dir of the module is in my workspace (like second approach)

---

*PS: Or am i completely wrong-thinking and should go for something completely different?*

Comment: Probably wrong-thinking but it's not entirely clear what exactly you want to accomplish. Why should `requirements.txt` be allowed to override the user's virtual environment?

Comment: I dont want to override the venv. I want to pip install a python module from github in editable mode inside my workspace using requirements.txt.  Technically it works. I done it manually like i wrote in second approach. I only want to implement that behavior inside requirements.txt for developing both projects in parallel. (Django-project uses this module)

Comment: Well, the short answer is no, there is no way for `requirements.txt` to affect where `pip` installs something, let alone performs Git checkouts. It would be a rather nasty surprise if it did that anywhere else than in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why did i ask such a crazy question?**

I thought i could make my life a little bit easier when both (package and Django project that is using this package) are laying editable inside my workspace because i work on them in parallel.

**My résumé**

I tried it a little bit with the second approach and at the end, i decided to prefer the first approach.

**Reason**

With both methods pydev won't show it as an installed package.

When mix both methots like that:

1. install package via *requirements.txt* (with the -e switch)
2. uninstall it
3. clone it into (eg. *~/workspace/*)
4. install it with the 'pip install -e .' inside the package

Then you will end up in a bad situation.
The 'virtualenv/src/' directory won't be deleted and is recognized as source for the package inside pydev.
When running the Django instance that uses that package, it runs the package-code from '*~/workspace/*'.

**Suggestion**

Use the first approach, import that source dir as project in pydev ('virtualenv/src/') and make a link inside the file-manager of your choice.
It will save you from a complicated mistake.